# Completely overriding Github branch with the Master branch

Tags: git, github

So I am working on a project for school using GitHub. What I am trying to do is basically wipe my branch, or completely override it so it is identical to the current master Branch

I have done some research on how to do this but I am unsure what the best way to do this is. I'm basically brand new to Github so I just want to make sure I don't screw anything up for my group.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Google for git reset --hard

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest two options for you.

Just delete entire directory and clone the code from GitHub again, as if it is your first time.

But, if I were you, I commit my changes into my branch with `git add .` and `git commit -m "Tried so and so, but will put this off for a while and come back later."` commands. You never know when you would need that brand new function you have created.

Once all your changes are safe, just do `git checkout master` and you will be back on master branch. However, before changing any code, please do a `git pull` to get all latest code from GitHub master.

Happy coding!